# xhr request (wordpress) — difference between $.ajax and non-$

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I am making an xhr request to wordpress in order to fetch some posts. I have two different sets of code, one that works and one that does not:

**Works** — outputs correct data to the console.

```
req = $.ajax
        url: ajaxurl
        method: 'POST'
        data: { action: 'get_grid_action' }
        dataType: 'JSON'

req.done (res) ->
        console.log(res)
```

**Does not work** — outputs null in res.body and "0" in res.text

```
request = require 'superagent'

request
    .post(ajaxurl)
    .send({ action: 'get_grid_action' })
    .end (err, res) ->
        console.log(err, res)
```

I have encountered this error before specifically with non-$ xhr requests and never really solved it. Due to project timelines, I have not quite figured out why a normal request would throw "0" and an $.ajax request does not. There is no error as I know that WP will return a 0 if it is successful (not to mention it also returns 200). I have tried several different xhr libraries with several different options and I can't seem to find the imbalance between the two.

Maybe there is something obvious I am missing, but does anyone know the difference between the two requests that might cause one to return "0" but jQuery to return the correct data?

Comment: *You* would need to inspect the request headers being sent to see what the difference is.

Comment: @KevinB Okay, I figured out how to get this working. I was mixing some thing up. Question, though. Why would the responseText be correct, but res.body still be null? In most xhr requests it seems that res.body and res.text are always identical. This may be a dumb question that shows I lack a true understanding of xhr requests, but I guess that is why I am asking it.

Comment: i would expect them both to contain the same data too. however, note that  whatever you are using to get res.body and responseText may omit that information in the case of an error.